# Points disappeared after changing CRS

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2

I'm having a problem with CRS and layers in QGIS & on Geoserver
What I'm trying to accomplish to change CRS of layers in importing.

I'm importing 'test.geojson' file in QGIS, and when I open points it says that there is WGS84 CRS set, & I'm trying it to use projected CRS since I need meters in EPSG:4326

But as soon as I change CRS with right-click SetCRS/SetLayerCRS and change it to WGS 84/ UTM zone 31N all the points disappear.

Does someone know what could be the problem?

Comment: @Ian Turton Im already using QGIS 3.0 but nothing is changing

Comment: **DO NOT CHANGE THE PROJECTION OF A LAYER USING SET CRS** - save a new file using export.

Comment: Thank you will try like that

Comment: @IanTurton Great now its working thank you so much